# get Locale from API.ai request

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using actions-on-google ApiAiAssistant node.js library with API.ai for designing my chatbot.

I have created a German API.ai Agent specifically for it. So, I need to get the locale value from the request to webhook to know which locale the request is coming from.

I have seen a method something like ApiAiAssistant.getLocale to get the locale information from the request but I am not able to find the specific one from the documentation.

Is the method deprecated? And how can I get the locale information from API.ai webhook request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `getUserLocale()` method. https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#getUserLocale

For example:

```
const app = new ApiAiApp({request, response});
const locale = app.getUserLocale();
```

It returns the language/locale combination (such as "en-AU").

If you're just using the JSON object and not the API, you can find the value at `originalRequest.data.user.locale`. This is the same value returned by the method.

If you just want a non-standard language field that is returned by API.AI, you can use the `lang` field. This isn't available through the API, just by reading the JSON directly, and only contains language information - not locale information. On the other hand, `lang` is available if you're using it for multiple platforms, not just Actions on Google. (But if you're using it for other platforms - you probably don't want to be using the actions-on-google node.js library.)

Comment: The request json consists of tag called lang. Does originalRequest.data.user.locale return that value?

Comment: {"id":"0f6c7194-8520-4cae-8949-dd26310ab8b1","timestamp":"2017-09-14T11:49:08.619Z","lang":"de"

Comment: No, the locale is a different value. Answer updated to clarify.

Comment: And, as noted, "lang" contains just language information - you specifically asked about locale information, which is a slightly different creature.

Comment: Note: app.getUserLocale() returns value only while using Actions SDK. Need to use language has to be identified on the integration platforms

Comment: You didn't mention you were using the other platforms. Answer updated. (Using the actions-on-google library with other platforms probably isn't a wise idea since you'll get a sub-standard response for those.)